# SSMS data import and export not maintaining view structure

Tags: sql-server

I have a remote SQL Server database that I need to export to my local machine for some testing and development. The remote SQL Server database is on a shared host and I have no access to the root directory where the backups are stored.

I opened SQL Server Management Studio and walked through the Import and Export procedure to export the remote database to my local server.  The remote database has tables and views and I selected the option to copy all tables and views and both data and schema and ran the export/import.  The database is created on my local machine and all the tables have the proper data, HOWEVER; the problem is that my views are not being imported properly.  My views are being imported as tables rather than the SQL that generates them.

Is there some setting that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing view via SQL Server import-export option, please try to script the view from remote server and create in local server, Assuming the views are referring to local tables. If you are selecting data from a different database you need to update the view accordingly..

[image: Script view as]

By right-clicking the database and selecting generate scripts from Tasks option you can script out multiple views.

Comment: I did try that, but ran into similar problems.  What actually worked for me was that the hosting company had the ability to dump my online MSSQL database to a file.  Despite the file not having a *.bak extension it actually was a backup and I was able to do a restore.